# Selenium: how to click on href link using text in tag <td>

Tags: python, selenium

I try to click on the link using text:

```
<td class="td_trdmrk_row"><a href="&#10;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#10;&#9;/wps/portal/!ut/p/c5/jY5NDoIwGESP1E9oKtsCsUVoBbRS2BASjYHITyIB4fTCAURnlpM3eShDS5tiKB9FX7ZN8UQaZST3PBpyn-3gZAgAaklFD0diADOXPSW5wyjH-wCAydgBD9vY4Mw2wDP_oeFLKPygE6QB5-fK6sTU62B2hks1R--XG5nS9ScRJCCkDm_XWNnUHaOU7BYmW1-3jNd9w0nytr6jrlZq6Pj4AXLkpM8!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSkthWWtLQ2xFS0NsRUpJL29Eb2dBRUlRaGpCS0VRQUNBRVpDZ0dRNEtRcGNFclN0Y1ZhQ0FHTUEvNEMxYjlXX05yeFFERVNaSUpSQ2t5WVNoRVJJX0FBISEvN19JSUFQSEtHMTBPMk0wMEE4TlVBRko2MkdTNS80MDk3NjAyMTAzNTcvYWNOYW1lL2NsaWNrUmVnaXN0ZXIvcmVnTmFtZS9SVVRN/">Реестр товарных знаков и знаков обслуживания</a></td>
```

I use the next code to get info from this [link](http://www1.fips.ru/wps/portal/!ut/p/c5/jY5LDoIwFEXXwgr6LAhMC8QWhcpHFDohJCpC5JNIUFi9sADQdwdvcHNuDhJoSp31RZ51RVNnTxQjoaa2TTx2oBs4YheA6Dwiu72KgcpTn6ipSQlTNAeA8sAEWzEUzKiBwZb_oWHhCPygLygGJQ1LvXWHLnZGsz-Vo_95Wb7MremXIeb87l3PQWQQqy3d4TExYl5dM577FSfOmuqGEiS0JTcablFbRVHfsndOJOkLSNVuEg!!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSmdwcGlRb0tVUW9LVVEhL29Gb2dBRUlRaGpFQ1VJZ0FFQUl5RkFNaHdVaFM0SldsYTRvIS80QzFiOVdfTnIwZ0NVZ3hFbVJDVXdwTWhFcFJBLzdfSUlBUEhLRzEwTzJNMDBBOE5VQUZKNjJHUzUvNWlwako2ODAzMDE0My80MDk3MTIyODU5ODUvYWNOYW1lL2NsaWNrUmVnaXN0ZXIvcmVnTmFtZS9XS1RN/):

```
def render_page(path, path_to_chromedriver):

    caps = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
    caps["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chromedriver,
                          desired_capabilities=caps)
    driver.get(path)
    time.sleep(3)
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Реестр товарных знаков и знаков обслуживания")
    link.click()
    r = driver.page_source

    return r

r = render_page(path_registered)
print(r)
```

But it returns:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a href="&#10;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#10;&#9;/wps/portal/!ut/p/c5/jY5NDoIwGESP1E9oKtsCsUVoBbRS2BASjYHITyIB4fTCAURnlpM3eShDS5tiKB9FX7ZN8UQaZST3PBpyn-3gZAgAaklFD0diADOXPSW5wyjH-wCAydgBD9vY4Mw2wDP_oeFLKPygE6QB5-fK6sTU62B2hks1R--XG5nS9ScRJCCkDm_XWNnUHaOU7BYmW1-3jNd9w0nytr6jrlZq6Pj4AXLkpM8!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSkthWWtLQ2xFS0NsRUpJL29Eb2dBRUlRaGpCS0VRQUNBRVpDZ0dRNEtRcGNFclN0Y1ZhQ0FHTUEvNEMxYjlXX05yeFFERVNaSUpSQ2t5WVNoRVJJX0FBISEvN19JSUFQSEtHMTBPMk0wMEE4TlVBRko2MkdTNS80MDk3NjA1MDE4NDYvYWNOYW1lL2NsaWNrUmVnaXN0ZXIvcmVnTmFtZS9SVVRN/">...</a> is not clickable at point (663, 623). Other element would receive the click: <html lang="ru_RU">...</html>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: On the webpage, I don't see any element with _linkText_ as  **Реестр товарных знаков и знаков обслуживания**

Comment: @DebanjanB open the link or see the part of html code (it's specified at the end)

Comment: A side note - I'm curious why are you passing phantomjs capabilities to a chromedriver?

Answer (score 2):

Fix that problem with

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Реестр товарных знаков и знаков обслуживания')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', link)
link.click()
```